# EF Code First and Database First in Same Project

Tags: entity-framework

As we are working on the refactoring of our current legacy code which is in Database first(EDMX files). We have decided to move on Code First approach, but moving edmx to Code First in a single go would create a lot of testing effort. Is there any way to run EDMX and Code First logic simultaneously in a single project for a time being (Planning to move few classes not completely in a single go).

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you try to use code first approach with existing database and for this, use reverse engineering tool to create an entities files from EDMX.

Comment: Will the database schema stay unchanged during the whole transition phase or do you need to prepare for changes while you maintain two models?

Comment: @grek40 I also need to maintain changes